# the same object for two separated initializations in python

Tags: memory-management, python-object, identity-operator

In Python, why do two variables reference the same object when they are separately assigned by equal values like in this example ?

example :

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> x is y
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin, one must understand a fundamental concept of Python, which is that everything in Python is an object.

So, in this case, in memory, Python has multiple Integer objects called PyIntObject which are C structs. Python when run, allocates memory for some integer objects in advance.

So during your script, when you use a new integer value, in your case `x = 5`, Python finds a free integer object block and assigns the value 5 to it. However, when you use the same integer value again, Python knows that it already has an object with that value, so it will point to the same object as `x` is. That is why `x is y` returns `True`.

If you want to read more about this read the following page:
https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/